# Redirect a subdomain request to another subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, ssl, redirect

I have an Azure app for years now many domains/subdomains are pointed to it. Now I enabled SSL for this application:

`Sub Application_Start()
   ....
   GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(New RequireHttpsAttribute())
End Sub`

I have a wildcard SSL for a TLD say xyz.com, which works for *.xyz.com too.

Now the problem is all the old domains say:

- http://test.abc.com should be redirected to https://abc.xyz.com
- http://test.mno.com should be redirected to https://mno.zyz.com
- and so on

I have created a database table which lists OldDomainName(http), NewDomainName(https) now basing on old domain requests those should be able to redirect to the new domain as permanent redirection.

Writing rewrite rules in web.config is not an option due to some reasons. And informing existing users the new domain is not an option.

Hope anyone can come with the best option.